# Split semi-colon separated values grouped within parentheses

Tags: google-sheets, split

My cell contains different "segments". Each parenthesis in the cell includes a budget, start date, and end date. I tried to work in Google Sheets.

What a typical cell would look like with multiple parentheses:

`(14268.0; 10/18/2018; 10/28/2018;); (52377.22; 10/29/2018; 12/02/2018;); (17835.0; 12/03/2018; 12/15/2018;);`

Is there a good way to split the budget and dates into their own cells?

Answer (score 0):

From A1 across to B1:J1, if placed in B1:

```
=split(A1,"(,;) ")
```